# Delete data from Google AppEngine datastore

Tags: google-app-engine

I need to delete some information from Google app engine datastore (not google app-engine cloud storage). I am using Java API for develop my application. Any one have good example for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this part of the documentation:
[Saving, Getting and Deleting Entities](https://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/entities.html#Saving_Getting_and_Deleting_Entities)

You just call `datastore.delete(key)`.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look to **Deleting Entities in Bulk** new feature [here](http://code.google.com/intl/it/appengine/docs/adminconsole/datastoreadmin.html#Deleting_Entities_in_Bulk).

> You can use the Datastore Admin tab of
>   the Admin Console to delete all
>   entities of a kind, or all entities of
>   all kinds, in the default namespace

Answer (score 0):

If this is a local environment, got to /_ah/admin/datastore and select entities to delete.